# Mapped drives disconnecting

Tags: windows-10, nas, smb, mapped-drive

We have some NASDrives, I have them mapped to my Windows PC as they are used often.

However, whenever my PC restarts, the drives are disconnected and I can't even browse to them through explorer if I go to \NasDriveName\

What I have noticed is that I can go to \NASDriveIP\ and this will show me the folder that I mapped, but I am unable to see any of the other folders on this NAS drive like I could before It restarted.

Has anyone else seen an issue like this? Could be something i'm doing wrong.

I mapped the drives by navigating to \NasDriveName\ and then right-clicking the folder I need and mapping it to a letter.

Comment: Can you reconnect the folders (log off, log on to see)? Can you map by a map string like NET USE T: \\name\folder ?   Is mapping persistence turned OFF (re-enable it)?

Comment: Is there any error message when you cannot access to the mapped drive? My understanding is you can access by \\IP\folder but cannot access by \\hostname\folder. Could you please run command **nslookup hostname of NASDrive** to see if its hostname can be resolved.

Comment: I wasn't able to map the drives without restarting my machine.

Comment: As far as I could tell it was giving me no errors. However,I got this sorted in the end by writing 2 batch files, one to disconnect drives and one to reconnect them and had them both run at startup.

Answer (score 0):

I got this sorted in the end by writing 2 batch files, one to disconnect drives and one to reconnect them and had them both run at startup.

Not really a fix, because I believe the drives should stay connected after a reboot. However, this seems to work for me.